# how to add 2 or more actions to navigation item?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

For example my navigation item opens menu but I want that it should dismiss keyboard also.

```
    openMenu.target = self.revealViewController()
    openMenu.action = Selector("revealToggle:")
```

in this case it is working correctly and opens menu. But when I add this :

```
    openMenu.action = #selector(dismissKeyboard)
```

the menu is not opening but keyboard is dismiss how to combine this 2 functions ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding two action to a button, you can try dismiss keyboard in your `revealToggle` function like this:

```
func revealToggle () {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    // continue your code
}
```

Comment: revealToggle function was written in another file and in objective-c I guess   - (IBAction)revealToggle:(id)sender
{

    [self revealToggleAnimated:YES];
}

Comment: I have just import this for menu

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Notification pattern.
You can add the your class as observer for notification as

```
// Register to receive notification
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourClassName.handleKeyBorad), name: menuRevealed, object: nil)
```

Add the selector to your button as

```
openMenu.action = Selector("revealToggle:")
```

Handle the notification in your class as

```
  func handleKeyBorad()
 {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
 }
```

In your reveal toggle method fire the notification as

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"menuRevealed"
                                                    object:self];
```

While using notification pattern do remember to register a class as well as remove as listener when not required. In did appear register as above, and did disappear stop listening to notification as

```
 NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: notificationName, object: nil);
```

------------EDIT-----------

In your reveal toggle add just this line

```
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction("resignFirstResponder", to:nil, from:nil, forEvent:nil)
```

It will resign all UIResponder. wont need to handle notification.

Hope it helps. Happy Coding!!